# Logging in to Raspbian + run a python script + logoff when python script ends

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

The python script is *only* a self refreshing npyscreen (curses) script displaying status every 1 minute. After user hits <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>, it should logoff.

Comment: How do you log in? Directly at the Pi or via _ssh_?

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/188132):

```
import os
import subprocess

def logoff():
    ppid = os.environ['PPID']
    subprocess.call(["kill", "-HUP", ppid])
```

You'll have to catch the [**`KeyboardInterrupt`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) exception:

```
def main():
    try:
        display_status()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logoff()


def display_status():
    pass  # your code goes here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're logging in using a remote connection, you should be able to set up [ssh key logins](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) to the Pi, and under home directory of the user account which you'll be logging in as, just edit `~/.bash_profile`.

`~/.bash_profile` is read and executed following a successful login, and configures bash according to specification. In this, you can load aliases, functions, and run any startup scripts.

As for the exiting on `^C`, though I've never done it personally, I would recommend importing subprocess and work out an error handler on Keyboard Interrupt to pass an exit back to Bash.